# Is this a script to help users to add new posts through a GUI?

Tags: html

These days, I decided to abandon WordPress and create my own website through Bootstrap3. But, I stopped in a point where I could not add new posts without manipulating an html page (to add a new title for my new article)  and link it to another html page (where the whole article is). I asked a few friends who are much better than me in web development, and they told me the only way to make a new post is through making and uploading a new html page to your server.

So, is what my friends told me true? 
There are a few websites that get updated every week like this one here: https://pythonprogramming.net

Does the website's owner append new html pages only to his website? That is impossible!

Comment: *"they told me the only way to make a new post is through making and uploading a new html page to your server."* - Either you misunderstood, or they were joking, or they do not know by far as much about web development as you think. Usually you'll just type the website *content* in a CMS (Content Management System) (like Wordpress) which is stored in a database on a server. Every URL is handled by the same script, which reads the URL, gets the contents of the right page, and generates a HTML page on the fly using a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you dicthed a CMS and created a static website which should act like a CMS?

Wordpress is a CMS, Content Management System, which for example gives you those dynamic links after you create content in the Dashboard.

Bootstrap is a framework which gives you the building blocks to create a template but it doesn't have any automation etc. what comes to publishing content.

If you're using static pages, ie. index.html & news.html, you need to create a new file for every new page (article) you're about to publish, ie. news-article-1.html and link to that file from the news.html. That's where your friends are correct. If you're planning to create a complex website with tens of pages & articles I'd recommend using some CMS, Wordpress is good for that. If you can't find a theme you like you can always create your own.

You can always build your own simplified CMS with dynamic links etc. but why bother when there's dozens to choose form.

The page you're linking, Python Programming, is using a CMS. I would guess one built with Django because of the folder structure.